# Android Paypal Checkout Options

Tags: android, paypal

I am finalising my app to make PayPal payments. It is just a one off payment so I don't really need all of the whistles that PayPal provides. I just want to click a button to make a payment and let PayPal do the rest.
It is all working now but I would like to tweek the UI that PayPal provides.
Specifically:

1). I don't want to see the authorised amount being more than the payment amount, they will always be the same as there is no shipping. I have already set Shipping Preferences to "NO-SHIPPING" which did remove the shipping address information.

2). I would like to remove PayPal Credit as an option.

3). I would ideally not wish the user to add a new card to the wallet at this stage. They can do that somewhere else if they wish

My checkout setup and sample screen is as follows:

```
paymentButtonContainer.setup(
            new CreateOrder() {
                @Override
                public void create(@NotNull CreateOrderActions createOrderActions) {
                    ArrayList<PurchaseUnit> purchaseUnits = new ArrayList<>();
                    purchaseUnits.add(
                            new PurchaseUnit.Builder()
                                    .amount(new Amount.Builder()
                                            .currencyCode(CurrencyCode.GBP)
                                            .value("6.00")
                                            .build()
                                    ).shipping(new Shipping.Builder()
                                            .address(null)
                                            .build()
                                    ).build()
                    );
                    OrderRequest order = new OrderRequest(
                            OrderIntent.CAPTURE,
                            new AppContext.Builder()
                                    .userAction(UserAction.PAY_NOW)
                                    .shippingPreference(ShippingPreference.NO_SHIPPING)
                                    .build(),
                            purchaseUnits
                    );
                    createOrderActions.create(order, (CreateOrderActions.OnOrderCreated) null);
                }
            }, new OnApprove() {
                @Override
                public void onApprove(@NotNull Approval approval) {
                    approval.getOrderActions().capture(new OnCaptureComplete() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCaptureComplete(@NotNull CaptureOrderResult result) {
                            Log.i(TAG, String.format("CaptureOrderResult: %s", result));
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Payment Approved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            },
            null,
            new OnCancel() {
                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Buyer cancelled the PayPal experience.");
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Payment Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }, new OnError() {
                @Override
                public void onError(@NonNull ErrorInfo errorInfo) {
                    Log.d(TAG, String.format("Error: %s", errorInfo));
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Payment Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
    );
```

and in the Application

```
 returnURL = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + "://paypalpay";

    paypalConfig = new CheckoutConfig(this,
            CLIENT_ID,
            Environment.SANDBOX,
            CurrencyCode.GBP,
            UserAction.PAY_NOW,
            returnURL);

    PayPalCheckout.setConfig(paypalConfig);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For (1) if the authorized amount during checkout is higher than the requested order amount, that cushion is probably being added due to [PSD2 overcapture requirements](https://www.paypal.com/us/cshelp/article/HELP954). You cannot adjust it yourself; contact PayPal about it.

If Pay Later is being shown as a button/action *before* reaching PayPal, there should be a way to omit it, analogous to `&disable-funding=paylater` with the web JS SDK ([interactive demo here](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server) for comparison). But if (2) and (3) would be changes to PayPal pages/activities, i.e. after the payer has essentially proceeded from your app to PayPal, changes are not possible.

Comment: I was hoping I might be able to use a parameter/preference for 2) and 3).  If I have said no shipping then surely there is no reason to authorise more than the payment amount as your link suggests it is like this to allow variations on shipping price.